# Packages not installing in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: package-management, 20.04

I am trying to install numpy package of python-3 in my Ubuntu 20.04. But I am getting error message saying:

```
dell@dell-Inspiron-15-3567:~$ sudo apt install python3-numpy
[sudo] password for dell: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-numpy : Depends: libblas3 but it is not going to be installed or
                          libblas.so.3
                 Depends: liblapack3 but it is not going to be installed or
                          liblapack.so.3
 wine : Depends: wine1.6
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
dell@dell-Inspiron-15-3567:~$
```

and also getting a red minus(-) sign in the top right corner of my screen.
Below is the image of the problem I am getting on the terminal.

[image]

How to solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1273483/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: Have you tried what it is suggesting? `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and update your package lists.

Comment: @kortewegdevries Yes, I did but nothing happend.

Comment: @Nmath by "nothing happened ", I meant the image I previously shared with the question the same output I was getting. But now I solved this problem and that issue is completely solved now. Thanks for your precious time gentlemen.

Comment: yes, I doing right now

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libblas3, and liblapack3.

```
sudo apt install libblas3
sudo apt install liblapack3
```

Comment: I did it, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps and your problem might get solved.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>